# When setting the size of a picture in html/css mobile, is the percentage width/height based on screen size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, oracle-apex

I am in the middle of Oracle Apex jmobile query project where I have an HTML page. This page contains the following image code :

```
<center>
<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#Logo.svg" align="center">
</center>
```

And the css to follow:

```
.img {
width:"50%",
height:"50%"
}
```

This code sets my image to the correct size when I am in portrait view, but when I switch to landscape orientation on my phone, the image doesn't re-size. So is the percentage method the correct choice or is there a different way? I also tried getting the screen width and height and dividing those values with no luck.

Comment: in css percentages are relative to parent container, in your case to the `center` element dimensions

Answer (score 2):

use img

not .img

```
img{
   width:"50%",
   height:"50%"
}
```

you have not set a class of class="img" on your img tag

Comment: To clarify: in CSS a `.` prefix means that it will match elements wwith the specified *class*.  Omitting the `.` means to match `img` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the articulation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the sizes relative to the viewport, you can also use view height and view widths (vh)+(vw), although it is not as [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) as %

Answer (score 0):

as 1l13v said:

> in css percentages are relative to parent container, in your case to
>   the center element dimensions

a good solution for responsive images ist to let them autoresize relatively to their size:

```
center img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

the computed width depends on the width of the parent container.

example:

```
center{
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```